# DatabaseCleaner fails on :transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have a Rails API that I am trying to test with Rspec. I have added in DatabaseCleaner for `mongoid` in Gemfile and run `sudo bundle install` but I am getting the below error.

Am I missing a config in any of these?

```
The DatabaseCleaner::Mongoid adapter has been extracted to its own gem: database_cleaner-mongoid, and will be removed from database_cleaner in 2.0. To silence this message, please replace `gem "database_cleaner"` with `gem "database_cleaner-mongoid"` in your Gemfile.
F

Failures:

  1) Users POST /api/v1/users creates a new user with valid details
     Failure/Error: DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

     DatabaseCleaner::UnknownStrategySpecified:
       The 'transaction' strategy does not exist for the mongoid ORM!  Available strategies: truncation
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:150:in `rescue in require_orm_strategy'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:146:in `require_orm_strategy'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:142:in `rescue in orm_strategy'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:133:in `orm_strategy'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:112:in `create_strategy'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:34:in `strategy='
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:19:in `block in strategy='
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:19:in `each'
     # /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:19:in `strategy='
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NameError:
     #   uninitialized constant DatabaseCleaner::Mongoid::Transaction
     #   Did you mean?  DatabaseCleaner::Mongoid::Truncation
     #   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:135:in `const_get'

Finished in 0.18763 seconds (files took 2.8 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/users_request_spec.rb:18 # Users POST /api/v1/users creates a new user with valid details
```

`Gemfile`

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner-mongoid'
end
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: Do not run bundler, gem install or any such with `sudo`. You're essentially giving any gem in the bundle superuser rights to do whatever they please to your computer. It goes without saying that's a big security problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message is pretty straight forward. You can't use the transaction strategy on mongoid. That config is for ActiveRecord.

The whole idea of between switching strategies was that transactions are much faster then truncating. But you could not rely on transactions to properly purge the database when running tests that where asynchronous.

Of course that not an option on Mongoid, and Database Cleaner is no longer even relevant on ActiveRecord.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
       example.run
    end
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```